# How to debug C# managed/unmanaged marshalling exceptions?

Tags: c#, debugging, com, interop, marshalling

I'm writing a DirectShow filter on C# and I don't want to use any third party library. This task is almost 100% based on the correct prototyping of the COM interfaces like IGraphBuilder, IBaseFilter, IPin, etc. And if the interface is prototyped incorrectly various exceptions at managed/native boundaries are thrown. The problem is to determine the location of the incorrectly prototyped interface method.

Currently I have:
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DirectShow.dll (this is the name of my managed dll) and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary

Call stack:

> ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject()  + 0xa bytes
>       KernelBase.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx()  + 0x9c bytes
>       clr.dll!CLREvent::WaitEx()  + 0x20f bytes
>       clr.dll!CLREvent::WaitEx()  + 0x1b8 bytes
>       clr.dll!CLREvent::WaitEx()  + 0x73 bytes
>       clr.dll!Thread::WaitSuspendEventsHelper()  + 0xcf bytes 
>       clr.dll!Thread::WaitSuspendEvents()  + 0x10 bytes
>       clr.dll!string "d:\iso_whid\amd64fre\base\ntos\r"...()  + 0x35688d bytes
>       clr.dll!Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC()  + 0x118 bytes
>       clr.dll!GCHolderEEInterface<0,0,0>::~GCHolderEEInterface<0,0,0>()  + 0x19 bytes 
>       clr.dll!Debugger::SendCatchHandlerFound()  + 0x150 bytes
>       clr.dll!string "d:\iso_whid\amd64fre\base\ntos\r"...()  + 0x3b9340 bytes
>       clr.dll!NotifyOfCHFFilterWrapper()  + 0x77 bytes
>       clr.dll!string "d:\iso_whid\amd64fre\base\ntos\r"...()  + 0x336941 bytes
>       msvcr100_clr0400.dll!__C_specific_handler()  + 0x97 bytes
>       ntdll.dll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException()  + 0xd bytes 
>       ntdll.dll!RtlDispatchException()  + 0x38f bytes 
>       ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatch()  + 0x2e bytes
>       KernelBase.dll!RaiseException()  + 0x3d bytes
>       clr.dll!NakedThrowHelper2()  + 0xc bytes
>       clr.dll!NakedThrowHelper_RspAligned()  + 0x3d bytes 
>       clr.dll!NakedThrowHelper_FixRsp()  + 0x5 bytes
>       000007ff00179486()
>       clr.dll!COMToCLRDispatchHelper()  + 0x4e bytes
>       clr.dll!SecurityDeclarative::CheckLinkDemandAgainstAppDomain()  - 0x40e bytes
>       clr.dll!COMToCLRWorkerBody()  + 0xd6 bytes
>       clr.dll!COMToCLRWorkerDebuggerWrapper()  + 0x22 bytes
>       clr.dll!COMToCLRWorker()  + 0x201 bytes 
>       clr.dll!GenericComCallStub()  + 0x57 bytes
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       quartz.dll!CEnumConnectedPins::CEnumConnectedPins()  + 0x4a bytes
>       quartz.dll!CFilterGraph::FindUpstreamInterface()  + 0x150 bytes 
>       quartz.dll!CFilterGraph::FindUpstreamInterface()  + 0xc1 bytes
>       quartz.dll!CFilterGraph::FindUpstreamInterface()  + 0x171 bytes 
>       quartz.dll!CFilterGraph::FindUpstreamInterface()  + 0xc1 bytes
>       quartz.dll!CFilterGraph::FindUpstreamInterface()  + 0x171 bytes 
>       quartz.dll!CFilterGraph::FindUpstreamInterface()  + 0xc1 bytes
>       quartz.dll!CWaveSlave::UpdateSlaveMode()  + 0xa7 bytes
>       quartz.dll!CWaveOutInputPin::RemovePreroll()  + 0x95 bytes
>       quartz.dll!CWaveOutInputPin::Receive()  + 0x12f bytes
>       msmpeg2adec.dll!CBaseOutputPin::Deliver()  + 0x22 bytes 
>       msmpeg2adec.dll!CIVIAudioFilter::DeliverOutSample()  + 0x3da bytes
>       msmpeg2adec.dll!CIVIAudioCodec::DecodeDDPlus()  + 0x556 bytes
>       msmpeg2adec.dll!CIVIAudioCodec::DecodeAll()  + 0x121 bytes
>       msmpeg2adec.dll!CIVIAudioFilter::Process()  + 0xda7 bytes
>       msmpeg2adec.dll!CIVIAudioFilter::Receive()  + 0x16d bytes
>       msmpeg2adec.dll!CTransformInputPin::Receive()  + 0x4c bytes 
>       msmpeg2adec.dll!CIVIAudioInPin::Receive()  + 0x3f bytes 
>       quartz.dll!CBaseOutputPin::Deliver()  + 0x22 bytes
>       quartz.dll!CBaseMSRWorker::TryDeliverSample()  + 0x14f bytes
>       quartz.dll!CBaseMSRWorker::PushLoop()  + 0x1da bytes
>       quartz.dll!CBaseMSRWorker::ThreadProc()  + 0x90 bytes
>       quartz.dll!CAMThread::InitialThreadProc()  + 0x1c bytes 
>       kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  + 0xd bytes 
>       ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  + 0x21 bytes

In other words the pipeline is:

1. Native code function named CEnumConnectedPins()
2. Native to managed transition -> If exception is thrown here then the xxx from step 3 is only known to marshaller but we're in the middle of nowhere.
3. Managed code method named xxx.

So this doesn't get me anywhere and I don't know how to debug that.

Comment: so did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 4):

This is *very* ugly to debug, the failure occurs in code you didn't write.  Go slower to diagnose this.  Write a native test program that obtains the interface pointer you want to test and verify the methods one by one, in v-table order.  The bad one will pop out.

Beware that C# doesn't support multiple inheritance.  Any COM interface that inherits from another interface that isn't IUnknown or IDispatch requires that you repeat the declarations of the methods in the base interface.  Forgetting to do this causes the wrong method to be called.  Or a non-existing one since the v-table is too short.  NullReference or AccessViolation is then a common outcome.